# Youtube API to find similar songs

Tags: youtube, discord

I've got a music bot which plays music from the Youtube API but I was wondering on how to get it so it plays the next song / similar songs to it.

It's a Discord Bot so I'm needing a way to implement it into that.

Comment: How do you access the YouTube API, and what language is the bot coded in?

Comment: My bot is coded in Javascript and I use Lavalink to access the Youtube API

Comment: Any ideas @DanP ?

Answer (score 0):

Using [YouTube Data API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3) [Search: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) endpoint thanks to [`relatedToVideoId`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#relatedToVideoId) filter, you can retrieve videos related to a given one by fetching:
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&relatedToVideoId=VIDEO_ID&type=video&key=AIzaSy...